# Back tracing errors generated in minified and obfuscated javascript file to original file without using source maps

Tags: javascript

I want to back trace errors that occurs in minified, obfuscated javascript files. For example error message like "**error in line 1: column 3000 ...**" in minified javascript doesn't give any meaningful information that can be traced easily.

Generally, people have used source maps to get exact location. I know how source-map works.

In my case I **don't want** to serve un-minified code (original source code) to public users( No issues of public access to minified). **Aim is to understand errors generated at user's browser without giving access to original un-minified source javascript file.**

The only solution left is to **trace back exact location in original un-minified source file from error message of minified and obfuscated file**. For example, If I get error message like **error in line 1: column 3000 ...**, I should be able to get exact line number in original script.

Has someone else faced this issue before? What are the solutions available? If yes, are they browser compatible?I am looking for some open-source solution.

Comment: you do you know that google console or any other text editor can un minified that file... is not issue for normal people since it makes not sense to argue about it...

Comment: Yes, they can un-minify file. There are libraries to un-mininfy also. But,functions, variable names will not be meaningful. Their will always be difference between original file and un-minified file.

Comment: you are talking about obfuscated code?

Comment: there is a difference between those two... ;)

Comment: Yes, I am taking about obfuscated code. Sorry for mis-typing.

Answer (score 0):

Make them run your unit tests with the minified code ;)